# How to toggle text of a button in jquery?

Tags: jquery

The text of the button is not changed back to "Show More". Why it is not working?

```
  $(".ld").siblings(".box").slideToggle();
  $(".ld").siblings(".box").each(function(){
    if($(".ld").siblings(".box").css("display") != "none"){
      $(".ld").text("Show Less")
    }
    if($(".ld").siblings(".box").css("display") == "none"){
      $(".ld").text("Show More")
    }
  })
});
```

Here is the link to this pen https://codepen.io/DineshRout/pen/BazVWGy?editors=0010

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) to add more code so that we can reproduce the situation from the code on this site.

Comment: Note that you can also use `.is(":visible")` instead of `.css("display") != "none"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should relate to the button itself instead of the siblings:

```
$(".ld").click(function () {
  $(this).siblings(".box").slideToggle();
  $(this).text($(this).text() === 'Show Less' ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`slideToggle()` is a animation that takes some time to finish. So when you click the button the first time, the animation starts and the value for display is indeed `!= none`, so your button text gets changed to "Show less". But when you click the button the second time, the animation still runs while your code that checks the value of the display style, therefore display is still not "none".

To circumvent this you can either use a callback function in your slideToggle():

```
slideToggle(function() {
    // this code gets executed after the animation finishes
    ... your code here
});
```

or use the button itself to toggle the displayed text:

```js
    

    $('button').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("show-more show-less")
    });
```

```css
.show-more:after{
      content: "Show more";
    }

    .show-less:after{
      content: "Show less";
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show-more"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this by having both texts in the HTML which means only changing one thing if someone decides the button text needs to be different.

```
<button class="ld"><span>Show more</span><span style="display: none">Show less</span></button>


$('.ld').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('.box').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
});
```